# How to verify the downloaded .iso file?

Tags: download

As elementary does not seem to provide md5 hashes of its `.iso`s there is no obvious way to verify that the downloaded file is actually intact / the correct one. What are the md5 hashes of the Luna and Freya release `.iso`s?

Are there other ways to verify the integrity of the images?

Comment: The torrent links will automatically verify their contents, but for direct downloads and a corresponding bug report, see my answer.

Comment: See also: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/where-can-i-download-older-versions-of-elementary-os

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Up-to-date hashes for recent releases are available from the [Verify your Download](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download) section from the Installation documentation.

Here are some checksums for older (no longer supported) releases, linked to the relevant Wayback Machine archive for that release, when available:

## [Loki 0.4.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20180517082248/https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download)

```
elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214.iso
sha256sum   5c499579e6ba05eed5626abbbb68fc1e3660e23ccb6a27f1a5f7794fed98bd56
```

## [Freya 0.3.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160614103641/http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download)

```
elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-i386.20151209.iso
sha256      97e143e762a1d1e3abac9eba33a59a7a6b9f319a7063cd47e406678c379fc683

elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-amd64.20151209.iso
sha256      ee737ffa6bf33b742c5a7cee17aa26dec5ee3b573cbbc4b53cbe2a2513c9197a
```

## [Freya 0.3.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907181424/http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation)

*The layout for the above Wayback URL is a bit messed up. It's still readable if you switch to "Reader Mode" in your browser, or search for `shasum` in the page source.*

```
elementaryos-stable-0.3.1-i386.20150903.iso
sha256      75b6cf0afc8a8d46bdcd646d5f22aac0496c3dd7bf8eafb8897933bfb7048f22

elementaryos-stable-0.3.1-amd64.20150903.iso
sha256      ca0f5933231fc2d75ef4e82c177c8150a3def9ddb78db8f24da1c6a0c6037390
```

## Freya 0.3

```
elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso
md5         742cc5b2c21bb1872954b13b7b2091a3
sha1        ff02eec5cba2c060fd3a5ac85b48d4075bb4f1a3
sha256      a7b8edfe95eb1c12745e02c63f830cad06ee756f552cba1cdca7bc30b7ca39e7
 
elementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso
md5         0ad75a048a89ee0bde5d7d333e5d5baf
sha1        4b82a9566c37464ca85eb29181e05cf538dd67f0
sha256      941ae370d27fe496fd10723a2803cfa52ddbce510ea502f20ec15a7127a68cab
```

## Luna 0.2

```
elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso
md5         a9db612a2406da80dfe4750747c0aca3
sha1        55569accf98578e2c3daf25329421d0248281e61
sha256      bfd2d56ec2936e7634f466372be6c839af12a8f7df956c0989664dcf9029da18
 
elementaryos-stable-i386.20130810.iso
md5         b48b6841b920fd0d4bee67aa68de4da5
sha1        393c54cc91b57ee9133cae28ca0852080527656d
sha256      fb00edb0037e3ed6e4d15e035bd9e450e148c1aa18a15e26c839fb550e075051
```

## [Jupiter 0.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430013522/http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/)

```
elementaryos0.1-jupiter-amd64.iso
md5         50f66928dd74cbeaf3fbd38b74f81adc
 
elementaryos0.1-jupiter-i386.iso
md5         c0f612d3d2e8c8cddc6a72a80f5f6480
```

Comment: As some people still have problems with Freya it'd be great if the hashes of Luna were available here as well.

Comment: @quassy Added Luna.

Comment: Thanks. Little typo, can't edit it because SE is stupid.

Comment: @quassy I got it.

Comment: @LewisGoddard thanks for your efforts getting these ISOs [preserved on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/@lewis_eustasy?and[]=subject%3A%22elementary+os%22). Any ideas for finding an authoritative source for hashes for the Freya (0.3) and Luna releases? I scoured the Wayback Machine, no luck. Freya was in the middle of the transition from elementaryos.org to elementary.io, to further confound things. It looks like they just weren't providing checksums on the web site at that time.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides I'm afraid I am probably the authoritative source for those, that was when we were moving from SourceForge to native downloads and the website was being rebuilt. We may not have gotten round to duplicating every feature we wanted for a little while. Maybe torrent/magnet files could act as a source of hashes if available?

Comment: Ha, "I _am_ the authority" is something I like to hear. `:)` Cheers to you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MD5 on http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/stable/, might be an idea for the team to make these a bit more easy to find on elementary.io. (It's the "i" button on the right there next to the downloaded graph icon)

[image]

**Update (2023)**: Since the project moved away from SourceForge, the "Files" tab has been removed. However, the MD5s for very old releases can still be found in the [Wayback Machine archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/) for that URL. Here's [an example for Jupiter](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202004538/http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/) (0.1), which jibes with [i386](https://archive.org/details/elementaryos0.1-jupiter-i386.iso) and [amd64](https://archive.org/details/elementaryos0.1-jupiter-amd64.iso) ISOs available on archive.org. I *just* downloaded and verified those two.

Comment: worth a notice that now elementary is not hosted on sourceforge http://blog.elementary.io/post/121768724076/goodbye-sourceforge

Comment: @Adityaultra indeed. Totaly forgot about that. The more reason to add some sort of reference to the MD5 checksum somewhere around the download link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that SHA256 hashes now seem to be available on the installation  [instructions page](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium).

Comment: My answer _does_ detail that on the first line.