# Why doesn't dd work to create live USB

Tags: release-freya, iso

My PC and laptop can't read the USB in BIOS or OS if it was created by `dd` command with elementary OS iso, but it works fine with other distros iso, no matter how many times that I download the iso file, it just won't work, the elementary OS iso only works with unetbootin.

-

-

1. MD5 check:

[image]

```
laichiaheng@PC:~$ md5sum ~/下載/elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso >file.md5
laichiaheng@PC:~$ md5sum -c file.md5 
/home/laichiaheng/下載/elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso: 正確
laichiaheng@PC:~$
```

正確＝correct

MD5 is correct.

-

2. dd command:

[image]

```
laichiaheng@PC:~$ sudo dd if=~/下載/elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso of=/dev/sdc
[sudo] password for laichiaheng: 
輸入 1744896+0 個紀錄
輸出 1744896+0 個紀錄
複製了 893386752 個位元組 (893 MB), 253.208 s, 3.5 MB/s
laichiaheng@PC:~$
```

輸入＝input, 輸出＝output, 複製了＝has copied

-

3. check:

And I removed the usb disk, then pluged it in again, I couldn't see my 8G USB unless I mounted it as root, and I couldn't see it in the BIOS menu either.

[image]  (elementary OS fail!!)

Then I tried Ubuntu

[image]

```
laichiaheng@PC:~$ sudo dd if=~/下載/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc
輸入 2039808+0 個紀錄
輸出 2039808+0 個紀錄
複製了 1044381696 個位元組 (1.0 GB), 297.45 s, 3.5 MB/s
laichiaheng@PC:~$
```

It appeared!

[image]  (Ubuntu success!!)

-

-

Please fix this!!

Comment: Worked for me perfectly, installed elementary OS 3 times from usb stick, used `dd` to create it. Give us more details about "how exactly" it didn't work for you

Comment: I also used `dd`. Perhaps your iso was corrupted on download? There are checksums for the iso's available [here.](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/513/how-to-verify-the-downloaded-iso-file)

Comment: What didn't work? I'll think about downvoting this question if you don't elaborate.

Comment: If I use unetbootin, it will generate a live usb correctly, but dd don't.

Comment: did you check the md5 hashes for the iso?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct

Comment: Using dd didn't seem to work for me either. I could not get my computer to boot from it (whether UEFI or legacy boot modes).

Comment: Do you have UEFI enabled on your computer ?
I had the same issue with my X1 Carbon, I used Rufus to build my UEFI USB bootdisk. Regards Nicolas

Comment: Yes, I have UEFI enabled on my PC and laptop.

Comment: Maybe not related to the actual problem but your "MD5 check" doesn't actually check anything. You first generate the sum based on the bits you have, then sum the file again and compare it to the one you just saved. So those will always match. The `- c` option is to validate sums supplied separately at the source of the file. The simplest way to check the sum is to Copy the sum from the terminal output (not directed to a file), then do a Find in the browser that displays the expected value.

Comment: 742cc5b2c21bb1872954b13b7b2091a3

Comment: It is the same as the origin iso from sourceforge, so...will they fix it?

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is mounting it as a normal flash drive, this has happened to me before and it seems the cause is a corrupted partition table. But even with this I can boot from it and install it without problem, it just won't appear in pantheon-files.

Comment: It won't appear in the bios of my laptop and PC either, but other distros do appear.

Comment: I'd recommend playing with your BIOS settings. E.g. turning on some legacy usb or legacy drive format support.

Comment: FYI. Because this post has non-latin (Chinese) characters to edit this post you need to add a empty line on top before submitting.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: (probably because) the partition is marked hidden.

A `dd`-copied USB stick booted fine on a few machines I tried. But these were 5-10 year old desktop boxes with BIOS.

The elementary ISO is an ISOHYBRID, like pretty much every distro these days. That means the disk image is both a bootable CD and an MBR-partitioned hard disk; a clever hack. But looking at the partition table, it is marked type `17` (hex), or "Hidden HPFS/NTFS". Of course, that's not what the partition is, hidden or not. Apparently that was the convention for a period of time.

It also appears that the ISO was built with Debian live-build 3.0, which is now a few versions old. Debian 6 also uses the same partition type. Debian 5 was not ISOHYBRID, and had no MBR. Debian 7 and 8, and other current distros use partition type `00`, which technically means "empty". That makes no sense either, but apparently it works better.

One more consistently visible effect of having a "Hidden HPFS/NTFS" partition is that the Files app or equivalent will not show it when you plug in the stick, for you to click-to-mount. But it is visible (and click-mountable) in the Gnome Disks app, for example.

Perhaps the particular BIOS/EFI you have also "honors" the partition type in the same way.

I changed that one partition type byte on the stick, and "elementary OS" appeared in the UI when I plugged it in, as you expected in your screenshots. As I mentioned earlier, it booted fine for me regardless, so I have no evidence on that aspect.

I tried to come up with a "one-liner" for you to patch the same byte so you could try it, but couldn't come up with something good. Maybe someone else might have an idea; or I could come up with a "three-liner" or "five-liner" if you really want to try.

Going forward, I have no working knowledge of the particulars of how elementary builds their distro, so it may not be as simple as "do it like this". But it seems like an issue they can track and prioritize.

Answer (score 2):

The elementary OS developers recommend using Unetbootin to burn the ISO to a USB key.

Source: https://elementary.io/docs/installation

Comment: Thanks, but it should work by using dd command, and it did months ago, maybe there is something wrong with their updates?

Comment: Julian maybe there is something wrong with your boot priority in BIOS? As you can see method works for everyone except you, and you still blame the OS? Makes me wonder.

Comment: No, my boot priority is fine, and as you can see it doesn't work for everyone, unless you haven't seen the comments.

Comment: I have given you every details that you were asking for, and you still say that it isn't elementary OS's fault! Then tell me why does dd work for every distros except elementary OS?

Comment: It is clearly and easy to see that elementary OS cause the problem.