# PGP Signatures of ISO Downloads?

Tags: security, iso, gpg

Does elementary OS PGP-sign ISO downloads? If not, is there a good avenue for requesting this?

Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch, Gentoo, and more all sign their downloads with GPG and provide cryptographic signatures verifying integrity and authenticity of their installers. As a security-conscious user, this is very important to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify the downloaded .iso file?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/513/how-to-verify-the-downloaded-iso-file)

Comment: See https://github.com/elementary/website/issues/1459

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS signs its distribution iso, cf. https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download (for elementary OS 0.4 (loki) they used `sha256sum`)

For older elementary versions you should check: [How to verify the downloaded .iso file?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/513/how-to-verify-the-downloaded-iso-file)

Comment: As an aside, cryptographic hashes are not the same thing as cryptographic signatures; hashes prove integrity and signatures prove both integrity and _authenticity_, that the file comes from the owner of a specific key.